# Error when adding referenc to Visual Web 2012

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-web-developer

I had the following error and i dont know how to solve it. I cannot add entity framework and if i quit it, I cant use it. It says that **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataBaseGeneratedAttribute exist in System.Data.Entity**
Here the image
[image]

And therefore i cant create any proyect with entity.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using an EntityFramework.dll built for an older version of .Net.

Delete all references to Entity Framework and re-install it from NuGet.